# Selenium GRID works incorrectly for the first time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a problem with selenium  hub/node. If i run hub and node for the first time after remote machine restart my tests are failed but if i run tests for the second time everything works correctly. Any idea? Why after machine restart tests are failed but without it for second execution are ok?

Thank You for help.

Comment: Did you manually access your remote machine after restart? Maybe there are some windows or popups or something? Maybe your browser opens "would you like to make *browser* your default browser?"

Comment: Machine is configured with autologin on admin account and with hub/node which are run by task scheduler.

Comment: Browser is open correctly without it becasue if i logged in i see that my app i testing by selenium but results are not the same for the 1 and 2 time